# Odoo 15 forecast report not working over ssl

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I am experiencing a strange error with Odoo 15. When I run a forecast report for a product if its done over SSL I get this error

```
Uncaught Promise > Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')
```

[image]

The strange thing is this only happening over SSL. When I run it over HTTP. I get no issues.

[image]

The only thing I can guess is that there is an issue with NGINX, but I have configured plenty of Odoo servers before with no issue, and I am running all the standard configs from the documentation. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/administration/install/deploy.html

I have attempted to change the system parameters on the setting with the same results.

Both the odoo and nginx logs show no errors.

Comment: can you turn on `assets debug` and reload the forcasting, check the error again and also chrome developer inspect section to see any stack trace shown there? Update with those informations.